# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) no such file or directory not found. ~(file does exist)

Tags: java, tomcat, runtime

im having a problem how to make this getRuntime().exec function to work i already checked the file was indeed there but it shows me an error of "no such file or directory not found"..

im trying to execute file using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() in a public tomcat server ,
this is the sample code :

```
public void toWEBP(File src, File dest) {
    try {
        String command = commandDir + (src.getName().endsWith(".gif") ? "/gif2webp" : "/cwebp");
        this.executeCommand(new String[]{
                command,
                src.getPath(),
                "-o",
                dest.getPath()
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebpIOException(e);
    }
}


String executeCommand(String [] command) {
    System.out.println("Execute: " + command[0]);
    System.out.println("File is exist before running Runtime exec? " + new File(command[0]).exists());

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    Process       p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String         line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebpIOException(e);
    }
    if (!"".equals(output.toString())) {
        System.out.println("Output: " + output);
    }
    return "";
}
```

this code works on my local tomcat server but when upload this to my public server it shows this error

```
Caused by: com.project.pio.WebpIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/tomcat/temp/cwebp_tmp/cwebp": error=2, No such file or directory
at com.project.pio.WebpIO.executeCommand(WebpIO.java:161) ~[classes/:na]
at com.project.pio.WebpIO.toWEBP(WebpIO.java:129) ~[classes/:na]
... 143 common frames omitted
```

updated my logs to check if the files is existing ..

```
    File is exist before running Runtime exec? true
2019-10-09 17:23:39.994 ERROR [project,47680f79a191e914,47680f79a191e914,true] 20729 --- [nio-7177-exec-1] com.project.FtpService      : Exception caught uploading file. By: dev
```

this is the sample command im trying to execute

```
/opt/tomcat/temp/cwebp_tmp/cwebp /opt/tomcat/temp/webp_1030637315080394686/testimage2.jpg -o /opt/tomcat/temp/webp_1030637315080394686/testimage2.webp
```

Comment: Is the file runnable by your user?

Comment: No, im the one who use the runnable file .. i need it to convert an image file such as jpg,png etc.. to webp format .

Comment: No I mean does the user that's running tomcat (i.e. `tomcat` most likely) have the rights to execute that program.

Comment: Ohhh  got it, ill ask it to person incharge about restrictions

Comment: thanks man, it seems that I / the program cant execute from temp folder as per the person incharge of server says .. i used the one that he installed directly to usr/bin